# Adding elem in canvas removes background and renders itself on a white canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Adding any fabric js element like text or any shape in canvas removes background which i have set earlier to my canvas and object renders itself on a white canvas. I want to load object on my canvas having background.

I tried renderAll() and bind() but it doesn't help at all.

Here c is another canvas and window.canvas is another one, I'm setting c as background of window.canvas. Everything is fine here

```
var ctx = window.canvas.getContext("2d");
var background = new Image();
background.src = c.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

background.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(background,0,0,this.naturalWidth,this.naturalHeight,0,0,window.canvas.width,window.canvas.height);
}

window.canvas.setHeight(c.height);
window.canvas.setWidth(c.width);
window.canvas.renderAll();
```

Issue when i draw this shape or any other fabric element it loads on a white canvas instead on my old canvas which is window.canvas with some background

```
shapCirEl.onclick = function() {
        var cir = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 60,
            fill: 'red',
            top: 100,
            left: 100
        });
        cir.set({
            borderColor: 'black',
            cornerColor: 'black',
            cornerSize: 6,
            transparentCorners: false,
            hasRotatingPoint: false
        });
        window.canvas.add(cir);
        window.canvas.setActiveObject(cir);
    };
```

When i draw this shape or any other fabric element it loads on a white canvas instead on my old canvas which is window.canvas with some background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setBackgroundImage](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setBackgroundImage) to set background image.

```
var url = c.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
window.canvas.setBackgroundImage(url,function(){
  canvas.renderAll();
})
```